# SQL Connection/Command proper management (to avoid table LOCKS)?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, table-lock

I'm setting up a connection factory for a .NET project, and I'd like to ask what is the best way for it.
I have an issue with the previous Log class not being able to write the logs properly because of table LOCKS (or so they say), so I'm tasked with setting up a new data layer that (hopefully) solves this along some other minor issues.

For now, the code:

```
public sealed class ConnectionFactory
{
    //Will be SQL only
    private static SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Development"].ConnectionString;

    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        if(sqlConnection == null)
        {
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
            sqlConnection.Open();
        }
        return sqlConnection;
    }
}
```

I'll be using mostly procedures, but may have one or another weird request and we'll type a query if needed, so I'm think I have to add a SqlCommand somehow:

```
private static SqlCommand sqlCommand = null;

public static SqlCommand GetCommand()
{
    //Check if sqlConnection is not null (omitted)
    if(sqlCommand == null)
    {
        sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    }
    return sqlCommand;
}
```

However, should this command be static? Or should I create a new one each time a new query is going to be executed?
Thinking in avoiding locks mostly, can it be caused by having multiple commands or only multiple connections? How do I avoid and deal with this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a "nolock" would work in this case...

```
FROM [table] with (nolock)
```

whenever you do a direct query.

Comment: I'll start using that for queries and procedures, but in the case I need a lock, could proper management of connection/commands solve it? I was thinking that if I use only one command and the application sends another request, the command would be "queued" to run after the current one finishes (as if it were a single user running multiple queries at once)